# Problem with IF AND and Vlookup nested formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to put a nested IF, AND and Vlookup formula. I want formula to return the value "0.17" in cell F3 if cell D3 has text "pasha" and B3 is not equal to cells mentioned in vlookup formula but its returns zero instead of showing 0.1. Please guide, TIA

=IFERROR(IF(AND(D3="Pasha",VLOOKUP(B3,G70:H78,2,0)<>B3),0.17,IF(VLOOKUP(B3,$B$69:$B$89,1,0)=B3,0.15,"")),0)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDhTL.png)

Comment: Show your data. Otherwise we can't suggest.

Comment: Your first VLOOKUP returns a value from the 2nd column. Are you sure it contains the category of data as your reference value B3? Btw, you may also note that VLOOKUP returns a #N/A if no match. P.S. You may want to use XLOOKUP instead of VLOOKUP

Comment: In this case: You may want to use e.g. MATCH instead of VLOOKUP as your target is not to return a matching value but rather whether the reference is in the reference table  or not (XLOOKUP as a better choice over VLOOKUP in general)

Comment: @Harun24hr i have added snapshot of sheet.

Comment: @Anonymous my excel version doesn't have xlookup formula

Comment: From your given screenshot your lookup table must start from `B70` not `G70`. So, `VLOOKUP(B3,G70:H78,2,0)` will be `VLOOKUP(B3,B70:H78,2,0)`.

Comment: Another point is you are looking for `B3` and comparing with `B3`, how it will work?

Comment: @Harun24hr about the VLOOKUP of B3 with B: OP tries to compare whether B3 is in the array in column B further down. Not the best solution but possible

Comment: Guys, what i am trying to get here in first part of IF formula is to meet two conditions ..first D3 should be equal to a text "Pasha" and then B3 value should not be in H70:H77 , only then F3 should return "0.17"...if you can suggest formula for that..

Comment: Your conditions are not working the way you  intent. Especially your first VLOOKUP does not produce a result you expect. See my answer and check if it’s working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to replace

```
VLOOKUP(B3,G70:H78,2,0)<>B3)
```

(Excel will unsuccessfully try to match B3 value with values from G column range while it contains different type of data:“Pasha”)

with

```
NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3,H70:H78,0)))
```

And feel free to adjust the second VLOOKUP accordingly.

Comment: @ anonymous  Thanks, it worked...never used NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH combination before. Will try to understand it logic )

Comment: No worries. MATCH will return you the row number with the match or N/A if no match. ISNUMBER returns TRUE if it’s a number or FALSE e.g. if it is N/A (result from MATCH). As you want no match, the NOT will just invert FALSE to become TRUE. For example, if you want to replace your second VLOOKUP you may want to leave out the NOT there as you are looking for the match.  P.S. feel free to accept/confirm my answer if it solved your question.

Comment: If you replace both VLOOKUPs you could also skip the IFERROR at the beginning because ISNUMBER takes care of it already in this case (by changing any N/A to FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

So, how about this:

[image]

You need to to sort the vlookup() but the process for testing the conditions is there.